# How to make Angular working with restrictive Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a problem thats made my project not working due to restrictive CSP

**index.html**

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src 'none';
      frame-src 'self';
      script-src 'self';
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
      font-src 'self';
      img-src 'self' data:;
      connect-src 'self'">
```

Comment: What console errors are you getting? Should give you a clue as to what 3rd party things are being blocked that you'd have to remove to use this policy.

Comment: add (blocked:csp) xhr